# Conditions when solving a non-homogeneous problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations, matrix-exponential

My question is taken from: [Finding the solution to a non-homogeneous matrix exponential.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2664395/finding-the-solution-to-a-non-homogeneous-matrix-exponential)

Rather than ask all my questions I considered to post them as a new question.
$$\frac{d}{du}  \begin{bmatrix}a\\b \end{bmatrix}  = \begin{bmatrix}-x& y\\ -y&-x\end{bmatrix}  \begin{bmatrix}a\\ b\end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix}\cos(zu)\\ -\sin(zu)\end{bmatrix}$$ where $P = \begin{bmatrix}-x& y\\ -y&-x\end{bmatrix}$. And I have it for $u=0:$
$$\begin{bmatrix}a\\b \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}0\\0 \end{bmatrix}$$

Having proved that $\exp\left[Pu\right] = \exp\left[-xu\right]$

$$\begin{bmatrix}\cos(yu)& \sin(yu)\\ -\sin(yu) & \cos(yu)\end{bmatrix}.$$

The solution to this was provided by the user 'Hyperplane':

$$ c(u) = \frac{1}{x^2 + (y-z)^2}e^{xu}
\begin{bmatrix}
x\cos((y-z)u) + (y-z)\sin((y-z) u)\\
x\sin((y-z) u) - (y-z)\cos((y-z) u)
\end{bmatrix} + \text{const.} $$

And to satify the initial condition $c(0)=0$ we need

$$ \text{const.} = -\frac{1}{x^2 + (y-z)^2}\begin{bmatrix}
x \\- (y-z)
\end{bmatrix}$$

The question that I have is whether the solution obtained would work for when x or y=0, or if x or y = z?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surely you would have to say that the solution is valid unless x=0 or y=z since the fraction would become 1/0; hope this is useful :)

Comment: This is much shorter than the Question you are responding to.  I feel that a useful answer would include more details about the validity or invalidity of solutions at $x=0$ or $y=z$.  As it is, you done little to shed little on a difficulty already highlighted in the Question.

Comment: @HidekiRyuga probably should have seen this, thank you for your help.